# MGF of "generalised" Negative Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, negative-binomial-distribution, moment-generating-function

Would the "extended" Negative Binomial have the same MGF as Negative Binomial? (See the definition of "extended" Negative Binomial below by Wikipedia)
[image]

Could someone please help provide the derivation of the MGF for "extended" Negative Binomial? In this case should we treat X as a continuous random variable or a discrete random variable?

Comment: This is not an "extended" or a "generalized" negative binomial distribution. It is just the usual negative binomial distribution as it has always been defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Negative Binomial distribution with (positive) non-integer $r$ is still a discrete distribution. You can tell by the fact that the PMF is defined for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$

Allowing $r$ to take any positive real value makes this a more flexible two-parameter model for discrete data. We often parameterise it in terms of the mean and variance. If $X \sim \mathrm{Polya}(r,p)$ we have
$$
\mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{r(1-p)}{p} \quad \text{ and } \quad \mathrm{Var}(X)=\frac{r(1-p)}{p^2}
$$
It is a popular alternative to the Poisson model for count data when there is overdispersion, i.e. the variance is higher than the mean.

We can work out the MGF in exactly the same way as for the integer $r$ case, that is, by exploiting the fact the PMF sums to 1 over the support.